# My input handling looks for "S", but when I type "S" the script just terminates

Tags: python, shuffle, card

I tried to make a UNO hand out system but it seems to not work:
when I type “S”, it just terminates. (It’s not very finished yet)

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

n = 0
command = input("Rules[R], Start[S], End[E] or Quit[Q]")

if command.upper == "S":
  while n < 7:
    pick_type = random.randint[1, 9]
    pick_colour = random.randint[1, 5]
    if pick_type == 5 or 6 or 7:
      pick_colour = random.randint[1, 4]
      if pick_colour == 1:
        colour = "Blue"
      elif pick_colour == 2:
        colour = "Green"
      elif pick_colour == 3:
        colour = "Red"
      else:
        colour = "Yellow"
      print(colour)
    elif pick_type == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
      pick_number = random.randint[1, 10]
      number = str(pick_number)
      print(number)
    else:
      draw_condition = random.randint[1, 2]
      if draw_condition == 1:
        card_type = "Wild"
      else:
        card_type = "Wild Draw 4"
      print(card_type)
    n += 1
```

And the result I get is:

```
Rules[R], Start[S], End[E], Quit[Q]
S

Process terminated with exit code 0.
```

Comment: `command.upper` is a function, not a string, so it will never equal the string `"S"`.  You want `command.upper()`.

Comment: It makes FURTHER errors!

Comment: In many parts of your code, you are using the wrong signature for the called methods, such as `random.randint[1, 9]`, which should be `random.randint(1, 9)` instead. Also, is the `n += 1` supposed to be where it is?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified version of your "pick" logic:

```
from enum import Enum
import random


class PickType(Enum):
    COLOUR = 0
    NUMBER = 1
    DRAW = 2


for pick in random.choices(list(PickType), weights=[3, 4, 2], k=7):
    print({
        PickType.COLOUR: random.choice(["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"]),
        PickType.NUMBER: random.randint(1, 10),
        PickType.DRAW: random.choice(["Wild", "Wild Draw 4"]),
    }[pick])
```

Note the use of `random.choice` and `random.choices` to simplify the random selection. Rather than generating a random integer and then figuring out which string goes with which int, you can use `choice` to just pick a random string directly.  The `choices` function allows you to weight the choices; in this case you wanted to have a 3:9 chance of a color, a 4:9 chance of a number, and a 2:9 chance of a draw, so we can just pass the weights `[3, 4, 2]` into `choices` to correspond to the three options (`COLOUR, NUMBER, DRAW`).

Telling `choices` that we want 7 choices (`k=7`) also removes the need for the incrementing `n` counter -- we just ask for 7 "picks", and then loop over the resulting `pick_type` values.  We then use a dict to translate each possible `PickType` to the resulting string, and print that string.